# How to derive discrete system model from satellite continuous model of unscented kalman filter?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, kalman-filter

How to derive the discrete system model from a continuous model. Below is the satellite's differential equation.
$$\dfrac{dr_x}{dt} = v_x, \dfrac{dr_y}{dt} = v_y, \dfrac{dr_z}{dt} = v_z$$
$$\dfrac{dv_x}{dt} = \dfrac{-\mu r_x}{r^3},\dfrac{dv_y}{dt} = \dfrac{-\mu r_y}{r^3},\dfrac{dv_z}{dt} = \dfrac{-\mu r_z}{r^3}$$

More specifically, the state vector of the unscented Kalman filter is
$$x=[r_x, r_y, r_x, v_x, v_y, v_z]^T$$
The system model has the form of $$x_{k+1}=f(x_k, u_k)$$
Thus, the question is how to derive the discrete model $f$ which has the above form? Or is it even possible?
Any reference or feedback is appreciated.

I come up with the following answer but not sure if it's correct or not. Please point out the error in the derivation if you spot one.
$$v_{x,k+1}=v_{x,k}+\Delta v_x = v_{x,k}+\dfrac{dv_x}{dt}dt = v_{x,k}+\dfrac{-\mu r_{x,k}}{r^3}dt=v_{x,k}+\dfrac{-\mu r_{x,k}}{r^3}\Delta t$$
$\Delta t$ is the time interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use some kind of integration method for ordinary differential equations. You already described one of the simplest of such methods in your question, what is also called the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). In its entirety this would give

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{k+1} \\ v_{k+1}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{k} \\ v_{k}
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
v_k \\ \frac{-\mu\,p_k}{r_k^3}
\end{bmatrix} \Delta t,
$$

with $p_{k} = \begin{bmatrix}r_x & r_y & r_z\end{bmatrix}^\top$ and $v_{k} = \begin{bmatrix}v_x & v_y & v_z\end{bmatrix}^\top$. This can get you close to the true change in position and velocity after a time step $\Delta t$ the smaller the time step gets, but will in general always be a little bit wrong.

There are other higher order integration methods, such as the [Runge-Kutta integration methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods). Another common integration method often used for systems like this is [Verlet integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration) which conserves energy and can guarantee long term stability of the orbit. However, long term stability of the predicted trajectory is probably not really relevant here since you only require a prediction over the time step $\Delta t$.

---

It is also (kind of) possible to solve it analytically. Namely, your dynamics can be described as a Kepler orbit whose [elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements#Keplerian) all remain constant except the true anomaly. The true anomaly can be found as a function of time by solving [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation), which in general can't be solved analytically but one can get arbitrarily close using numerical methods.

---

It can be noted that the added accuracy of the analytical solution might be overshadowed by the noise on the measurements of the state vector. So in many cases I think that integration methods would yield sufficiently good predictions. Additionally, the integration methods would also allow for external forces, such applied thrust.

Comment: In the first paragraph, you state "in general always be a little bit wrong". Is it because that if this system is highly dynamic, then the error will accumulate with time.

Comment: @LionLai It is not necessarily due to the complexity of the dynamics, but probably mainly due to the energy conserving nature of the dynamics. Namely, one can also see similar behavior with a simple mass-spring system. When using the (forward) Euler method you often get some spiraling in or out action, as is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53870289/2249414). However, for a UKF (or any kind of observer/state estimator for that matter) you also periodically do a correction step using measurements, so this drift over time shouldn't really be an issue.